# Is sorting the database via a custom function inefficient?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, linq, entity-framework-core

I have a table with `Id` and `Text` fields. The `Text` field holds sentences, averaging 50 words. There are >1,000,000 rows.

This is part of a web app where users need to be able to search through these sentences. Here's the twist though - **I need to be able to run a custom search function written in C# that uses Machine Learning** instead.

From what I understand, this means **I'll have to download the entire database of >1,000,000 rows every time a user makes a search**! This seems really inefficient to me.

How would you implement this in the most efficient/fast way possible?

If this is relevant, I'm using EF Core with LINQ `.Where(my_custom_search_function)`, with a PostgreSQL database

Comment: Are you asking about sorting? or searching via C#?

Comment: Both. My search function is basically a function that accepts 2 items and compares them. I'm currently downloading all the rows and sorting them with that function then returning the top 5. I don't care if the answer is C#-specific, maybe there's a solution that only involves SQL/the database?

Comment: have you considered ["full text search"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch.html) a blog: [Postgres full-text search is Good Enough!](http://rachbelaid.com/postgres-full-text-search-is-good-enough/)

Comment: That is really cool! Sadly I need to run a more complex search function that is a black box to me. It is actually a REST microservice that uses tensorflow under the hood.

Comment: I would suggest you to use some kind of caching. So every time user search you wont need to download entire database. SQL 2017 has integrated machine learning with python and R in sql directly so you could do a stored procedure and do all your processing there and return the result from the endpoint, please check similar in psql

Comment: You can create C-functions in Postgres then you can use them in a `WHERE` clause in SQL.

Comment: @Eldho sadly there is nothing similar in postgresql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found the solution. Postgresql full-text search currently provides [two ranking functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/textsearch-controls.html#TEXTSEARCH-RANKING). In this case "sorting" in the question and "ranking" here refer to the same thing.

Postgresql docs state:

> However, the concept of relevancy is vague and very application-specific. Different applications might require additional information for ranking, e.g., document modification time. The built-in ranking functions are only examples. **You can write your own ranking functions and/or combine their results with additional factors to fit your specific needs.**

These functions can any of the [four kinds of supported postgresql functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/xfunc.html).

Then they answer this exact question:

> Ranking **can be expensive** since it requires consulting the tsvector of each matching document, which can be I/O bound and therefore slow. **Unfortunately, it is almost impossible to avoid** since practical queries often result in large numbers of matches.

Credits to @Used_By_Already for pointing me to Postgresql full-text search.